# Zabbix cannot connect to a PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, monitoring, postgresql, zabbix

First off I am running CentOS 6.5 and attempting to use Zabbix 2.2.4. Any hostnames have been replaced with examples.

I have installed the following RPMs onto my Zabbix machine ( hostname will be zbx-hostname ):

```
zabbix-java-gateway-2.2.4-1.el6.x86_64
zabbix-web-2.2.4-1.el6.noarch
zabbix-agent-2.2.4-1.el6.x86_64
zabbix-server-2.2.4-1.el6.x86_64
zabbix-2.2.4-1.el6.x86_64
zabbix-web-pgsql-2.2.4-1.el6.noarch
zabbix-server-pgsql-2.2.4-1.el6.x86_64
```

My PostgreSQL machine has postgreSQL 9.2 installed with the RPMS ( hostname will be db-hostname ):

```
postgresql92-9.2.8-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
postgresql92-libs-9.2.8-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
postgresql92-server-9.2.8-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
```

My zabbix_server.conf file looks like:

```
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_server.log
LogFileSize=0
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbix_server.pid
DBHost=db-hostname
DBName=zabbix-dbname
DBUser=zabbix-user
DBPassword=zabbix-password
DBSocket=
DBPort=5432
```

My zabbix php configuration looks like:

```
$DB['TYPE']     = 'POSTGRESQL';
$DB['SERVER']   = 'db-hostname';
$DB['PORT']     = '5432';
$DB['DATABASE'] = 'zabbix-dbname';
$DB['USER']     = 'zabbix-user';
$DB['PASSWORD'] = 'zabbix-password';

// SCHEMA is relevant only for IBM_DB2 database
$DB['SCHEMA'] = '';

$ZBX_SERVER      = 'localhost';
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
$ZBX_SERVER_NAME = '';

$IMAGE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG;
?>
```

I am able to run the following and successfully connect to my database:

```
export PGPASSWORD=zabbix; psql -U zabbix-user -d zabbix-dbname -h db-hostname
export PGPASSWORD=zabbix; psql -U zabbix-user -d zabbix-dbname -h 192.168.0.1
```

But zabbix refuses to connect printing out (192.168.0.1 being the correctly resolved IP Address) :

```
25015:20150205:112656.236 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix-dbname' failed: [0] could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running on host "db-hostname" (192.168.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

25015:20150205:112656.236 Database is down. Reconnecting in 10 seconds.
```

But on the DB host when I monitor incomming TCP traffic I do not see any incoming connections ( using both tcpdump & iptables ). It appears that zabbix is not even attempting to make a request to the database box?

I have torndown my zabbix box and rebuit it to get the same error twice so it would appear to be a problem with my configuration, does anybody know of any solutions?

Comment: I've managed to resolve the issue, SE Linux was enabled incorrectly and was blocking zabbix from networking. To solve the issue I ran: setsebool -P zabbix_can_network 1. The topic discussing this can be found at (Warning: In russian): https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=47247

Comment: Thanks for following up with the solution. Please post as an answer-to-self when you can, and I'll +1 if you @reply me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From previous comment:

I've managed to resolve the issue, SE Linux was enabled incorrectly and was blocking zabbix from networking. To solve the issue I ran:

```
setsebool -P zabbix_can_network 1
```

The topic discussing this can be found at (Warning: In russian): http://zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=47247

Answer (score 2):

In my situation I need to grant network access for httpd too. (CentOS 7, zabbix 3)

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

If you have error "setsebool, command not found" install policycoreutils-python

```
yum install policycoreutils-python
```